# Features listed in ManageFeatures.aspx that should not be there

Tags: feature

I go to ManageFeatures.aspx and I see bunch of features that don't belong there and they are not in the 14 hive's feature folders. I go to the backend database and look in alldocs, features, and featuretracking tables and don't see them. Now, where do they came from and how do I get rid of them?

http://Portal.SCJohnson.com/SalesNW/_layouts/ManageFeatures.aspx?Scope=Site

Comment: Have you upgraded to SharePoint 2010 recently? Also, which Features are they? Custom-added ones?

Comment: Yes, migration was performed long before I came on board. Trying to clean these up before SP1. And I could not find the old features anywhere. The old developer is gone and took knowledge with him.

Answer (score 1):

You could use PowerShell to get the GUIDs of the features you want to get rid of, here's a blog form Glyn Clough on how to do this: http://www.glynblogs.com/2010/08/powershell-commands-to-list-sharepoint-features.html

Then, use `stsadm -o uninstallfeature -id <feature_guid>` to uninstall the feature (might be able to do the same with PowerShell, I think).

Comment: James, get-spfeature is same as looking inside the content database. thoese features dont show up using get-spfeature but they are listed on the managefeature page.

Comment: It it be part of a solution on a site collection?

Comment: Delete from dbo.solutions

Now all the junks from sp2007 are gone. what a pia (pain in a air)

Comment: Have you contact Microsoft about this solution yet? Directly editing the content database renders your environment completely unsupportable by Microsoft, and is highly discouraged in any and all circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming they these "orphaned features" are active, you can click the deactivate button and note the featureid in the querystring.  With that you should be able to use STSADM **deactivatefeature** and/or **uninstallfeature** with the force option to remove them.

Comment: Hello Rob, Actually, they are not activated so not found when I do get-spfeature. However, if i activate them i get an item created in feature table with brand new guid n everything. i can also de-activate them.

Comment: Delete from dbo.solutions

Now all the junks from sp2007 are gone. what a pia (pain in a air)

Comment: Just curious, did you try STSADM uninstallfeature once you had the feature GUID?  Assuming that worked/would have worked it would be a preferred solution over directly deleting rows from the database.